# everytime I try to compile this code it gives me this warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int] BuildMaxHeap(int A[], int n) {

Tags: c, linux, sorting, data-structures, vnc

```
BuildMaxHeap(int A[],int n) {
    int i;
    for(i=(n/2)-1;i>=0;i--) {
    MaxHeapify(A,n,i);
```

code doesnot compile give error message warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]  BuildMaxHeap(int A[], int n) {

Comment: you have to say what type the function returns

Comment: `int BuildMaxHeap(int A[],int n) {` ... or `void BuildMaxHeap(int A[],int n) {` ... or ...

Comment: Try firing up your favourrite search engine and typing in: "return type defaults to ‘int’"